# Connect to ISPConfig 3 without WSDL

Tags: json, python-3.x, http, ispconfig

I need connect to ISPConfig 3 with python 3.5 without WSDL and get data from it. I didn't find anything useful yet, maybe someone have tried it already or have any suggestions, tips or example code? There are some examples for php, but nothing fresh for python.

**SOME CODE**

At the moment I have this, but I have no ideas if it's even something working and useful, but at least something.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        username = 'usr'
        password = 'usrpswd'
        url = 'https://link/remote/index.php'
        uri = 'https://link/remote'

        client = SoapClient(
            location=url,
            trace=True,
            http_headers={'Authorization': 'Basic %s:%s' % (username, password)}
        )
```

**OTHER SOURCES**

Also I have found this [ipsconfig-json-wrapper](https://github.com/bolvarak/ispconfig-json-wrapper) and after I placed files in folder and go to `http://{domain}/remote/json.php?method=login&username=fubar&password=boobaz&callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

I get `typeof JSONP === 'function' && JSONP({"success":true,"response":"**************************"});`

Maybe someone could help now to make GET request and get some data or at least explain what should I do next?

Comment: If you check the source files which are bundled with ISPconfig, there a load of API scripts including a soap config file. These are written in PHP but could give you the option of calling PHP scripts from within python. Just an idea.

Comment: @fyberoptik I tried json-wrapper and seems it might work. You can put method in url and call for example "get_domain" or something. But it ask for session ID, so need to think about that.